# Can a Bridge forward frames with the destination as broadcast/multicast

Tags: layer2, multicast, broadcast, bridge

I have a question regarding multicast and broadcast frames on a network bridge.

Will the bridge forward these frames from one network segment to another network segment ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming there is only a single VLAN configured, switches (aka transparent bridges) will forward L2 broadcasts to all other network segments, except the segment that originated the frame. Similarly, L2 multicast traffic is treated as "unknown unicast" and is also forwarded to all other network segments.

And while I hate to be that guy, you could have had the answer to this with 10 seconds of googling, so I downvoted the question.

Comment: Hi , I am talking about bridge not switch .

Comment: A bridge is the same thing.